Relation between three entities in Hibernate with a self-refernce many-to-many
Table diagram
I have a MySQL database, with a table "type" and a table originated by a self-reference many-to-manytable, "type_combination", that also have a many-to-one relation with another table, "type_of_weakness". I'm having some issues with the mapping of this relationship with Hibernate-JPA. I don't want tyo change database, even if I can, because I want to learn how to manage this kind of relationship.
Maybe could be helpful to know that tables represent Pokémon's type and their efficacy of moves for the combination of types.
Actually I have the entity for the table "type" and the entity for the table "type_of_weakness".
I tried some approaches

To represent the self-reference many-to-many relationship on my Type-entity

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "def")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"def", "att"})
    private List<Type> att;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "type_combination")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"def", "att"})
    private List<Type> def;


The problem with this is that I don't understand how to mapping the many-to-many relationship between the resultant table and "type_of_weakness".

To create the entity for the table "type_combination" and mapping the many-to-one relationship between this table and  "type_of_weakness".

This is my entity for "type_combination"
@Entity
@Table(name = "type_combination")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TypeCombination {

    @EmbeddedId
    private TypeCombinationId id;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "type_of_weakness_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"combinationList"})
    private TypeOfWeakness weakness;

}

This is in my entity for "type_of_weakness"
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "weakness")
    List<TypeCombination> combinationList;

The problem with this approach is that I'm not able to define the relation between "type_combination" and "type".
This is the Json response of my API for a row of "type_combination":
{
  "id": {
    "attTypeId": 2,
    "defTypeId": 2
  },
  "weakness": {
    "id": 1,
    "typeOfWeakness": "not-so-effetctive",
    "value": 0.5
  }
}

The fact is that I want to access to all properties of the entity Type from this entity (like it happen for "type_of_weakness").
It needed to add another class, TypeCombinationId to describe the id composed by the two foreign key and it cause me some issue when I try to define some kind of relationship between Type and TypeCombination.
This is my id class:
@Embeddable
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TypeCombinationId implements Serializable {

    private int attTypeId;
    private int defTypeId;
}

I tried to set this property of class Type instead of int and define some kind of one-to-one or one-to-many relationship with Type but I have some error about the fact that I can't set this kind of relationship on id, and in generally I'm not sure about the best way to manage this relationship.
Actually my final goal is to have for every type the list of all the combination with the weakness.
Thank you all for help.
